# Users not associating with object on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

For some reason my users aren't associating with the object when the object is created. Each time that I add a new "industry" the user_id is just coming up as nil. I'm able to update this in the console but it's not working when I create the industry.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :industries
 has_many :categories
 has_many :startups
end
```

Industry.rb

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :categories
end
```

industries_controller.rb

```
class IndustriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_industry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @industries = Industry.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    authorize @industries
  end

  def show
    @categories = @industry.categories
  end

  def new
    @industry = Industry.new
    authorize @industry
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @industry = Industry.new(industry_params)
    authorize @industry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @industry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @industry, notice: 'industry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @industry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @industry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @industry.update(industry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @industry, notice: 'Industry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @indsutry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @industry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @industry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to industries_url, notice: 'Inustry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_industry
      @industry = Industry.find(params[:id])
      authorize @industry
    end
   # def correct_user
     # @industry = current_user.industries.find_by(id: params[:id])
      #redirect_to industries_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this Industry" if @industry.nil?
   # end

    def industry_params
      params.require(:industry).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "industries", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "role"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Comment: I'm curious; where in your code do you assign a `user` to the `@industry` object? I can't seem to find that anywhere, which could well be the reason for `user_id` being `nil`.

Comment: Is the Industry meant to belong to what user? are you sending it from the form? or how do you expect it to get populated? Just write it in the same way you said you are assigning it from the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def create
   @industry = Industry.new(industry_params)
   authorize @industry
   @industry.user = current_user
   # blah-blah
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Still learning the finer points of RoR. Now I get it. appreciate the help.

Comment: If you want that on one  line:

`@industry = Industry.new(industry_params.merge(user: current_user)`